# Cannot telnet host from ec2 instance behind a proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, aws, telnet, squid

Let me try to rephrase the whole question as it was not very clear the first time.
I need to understand and workout port forwarding. I have an **ec2** instance running behind a proxy server. I need to telnet from my ec2 instance to a server outside, 'in internet' through port (let's say) 1919 . In **security groups** I have allowed `tcp` traffic on port 1919 from my `ec2` instance to the proxy and back and from proxy to the remote server.
To be able to telnet from my ec2 instance to remote server, i think i will have to port forward 1919 in proxy to be able to get to the remote server. I tried it with
 `iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 9093 -j DNAT --to *ipaddofEC2*:1919`
`iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d  --dport 1919 -j ACCEPT`
In my **squid** I have :
`acl servicebus_port_9093 port 1919` and
`http_access allow allowed_source_hosts allowed_messaging_sites servicebus_port_9093`     and
`acl allowed_messaging_sites dstdomain .servicebus.windows.net`(remote host's url finishes with windows.net)
Still I have not been able to telnet from my `ec2` to remote server.
Ps. ip forwarding is on in proxy and I tried to tcpdump in proxy while trying to telnet from my ec2 instance to remote server but I get nothing. (I dont know much about tcpdump)
**I get timeout error**.

Comment: not completely clear to me, by the way it looks more a firewall issue than a proxy one. i would suggest tcpdump on your "xyz port" to better understand what's going on.

Comment: in short, i want to telnet from my ec2 to a remote host but i cannot, as every traffic has to pass from the proxy. I can telnet proxy and proxy can telnet the remote host.

Comment: is that proxy in transparent or forwarding mode? you had to explicitly configure that client to use it?

Comment: its a transparent proxy. yes ,it was configured by us for the client

Comment: so you got a firewall onboard, or at gateway side (can't tell about your network), that is redirecting web ports to squid. this mean that if you telnet ports not related to web (pick one) it succeeds, right?

Comment: I am lost...we have security groups and we have to explicity allow a service to run on a specific port and all other ports are blocked, apart from proxy outbound which is set to 0.0.0.0/0 for the port xyz(which is 9093)

Comment: ok, so let's say that everything is sent to proxy, in this case you should have some lines in squid.log (maybe with TCP_DENIED status). if not, you should log something on your firewall. one of the two.

Comment: In squid logs there is nothing related to port 9093. By firewall you mean ip tables?

Comment: iptables if you're using it of course. sorry it's getting too long but i give you an advice. try to explicly open forward chain from your client to remote host. 
es. iptables -I FORWARD -s $client -d $host -j ACCEPT.
also try to tcpdump port 9093 and see if you spot bidirectional traffic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will follow your advice and check if it helped.

Comment: if still in trouble please edit your question in this way: OS of all clients/hosts involved, squid (main) configuration, firewall type and in which way traffic gets redirected from gateway to proxy. good luck

Comment: Just checked iptable, it's empty with all columns "Accept". Let me tcpdump on the port and edit my question. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol used was not tcp but a 'special' protocol that's why I was not able to tunnel the traffic through.
The port was used by Kafka and it's their own protocol as far as I know, which is not supported by squid.